# "LIMIT" using column as delimiter

Tags: php, mysql, limit

Hello Fellow PHP/MySQL Gurus

Today, I was presented with a problem while coding a project. The problem is as follows. I am polling information from my user account table to be displayed and later used as a webpage account editor. I have all of the background PHP complete. It works fine. While "SELECT"ing my information, I am asking for 2 columns. User ID and Full Name. Below is example data:

```
User ID | Full Name
11234   | John Doe
11235   | Jane Doe
11236   | Amanda Hug
11236   | Amanda's Tablet
```

This data (as with my physical data) has users whose name and uid is saved. In this example (and again, my physical data), a user (Amanda) has 2 accounts, stored under the same UID (this is done intentionally for personal reasons). When I "SELECT" the users, I want to only have one **Amanda** appear. Such as:

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT `uid`,`Name` FROM `User_Accounts` WHERE ... ");
```

The **...** representing the portion of code where I "**LIMIT 1**" to the UID field.

Comment: you can simply separate first name and second name by changing your table structure if I am not misunderstood, or `group by UID` which group similar UID and shows only one

Comment: Why not use a `DISTINCT uid` ?

Comment: @Akam Group By. I was not familiar with its function. Works perfectly. I was not trying to seperate name, just show single uid's.

Comment: Remember that `GROUP BY` goes after `WHERE`.

Comment: @woofmeow I choose not to use distinct uid's. I want to have the same user have the same uid. It doesn't matter which account they sign into, their actions will be marked as the same uid.

Comment: @ironcito that's incorrect you can use it without `WHERE`.

Comment: @Prix Well, yeah, but if you use `WHERE`, you must put `GROUP BY` after it.

Comment: @Prix He uses a `WHERE` in his code, so I was just pointing out that `GROUP BY` goes after it, since no one had clarified that when they suggested using it.

Comment: @Prix I don't think I said that, but let's leave it at that!

Comment: `Remember that GROUP BY goes after WHERE.`, GROUP BY should come after WHERE when its being used but may as well come after FROM or inside sub queries, etc depending on your query/needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT `uid`,`Name` FROM `User_Accounts` GROUP BY `uid`");
```

`GROUP BY` is the best way to extract multiple data, since that data has the same ID you can use `GROUP BY`.